# How to setup insight explorer?

Tags: insight-api

How to setup insight explorer and using its API?

https://github.com/bitpay/insight

Please your detail instruction to install and setup it.

Comment: The readme.md for that project says *"THIS PROYECT HAS BEEN REPLACED BY BITCORE-NODE, AT https://github.com/bitpay/bitcore"*. If you want to use obsolete unsupported software you can try checking out the previous versions of readme.md

Comment: Do you instruction detail how to setup it ?

Comment: See prior versions of readme.md

Comment: can you help to share me ?

Comment: https://github.com/bitpay/insight/commit/34a4b3585c942f2eb7772066f85c4157023c4d5b